# MVC3 - Error on Build (Inconsistant accessibility)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I get an error on line 14 of the below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TimeDb.Models;

namespace TimeDb.Areas.Stock.Models
{
public class ProductAddViewModel
{
    private readonly DatabaseDataContext _db = new DatabaseDataContext();
    public SelectList ProductTypes;
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public ProductAddViewModel()
    {
        Product = new Product();
        PopulateLists();
    }

    public ProductAddViewModel(int id)
    {
        Product = _db.Products.Single(p => p.Id == id);
        PopulateLists();
    }

    private void PopulateLists()
    {
        ProductTypes = new SelectList(_db.ProductTypes.OrderBy(pt => pt.Name), "Id", "Name");
    }
}
```

}

Now, this has only appeared since I tried adding a new field to Database.cs.

What I was trying to do was to add a new field, I had added within a database table. But the error appeared above.

Part of the database code I tried changing was:

```
 #region Product
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetaData))]
partial class Product
{

}

public class ProductMetaData
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Retail Price")]
    public double RetailPrice { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Threshold")]
    public int Threshold { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Number To Keep In Stock")]
    public int NumberToKeepInStock { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Shelf")]
    public string Shelf { get; set; }

}
```

I added:

```
[DisplayName("disabled")]
public int disabled { get; set;}
```

Most likely I am not aware of the best way of adjusted my database code once I adjust the table. But when I remove the above amendment, it still shows the same error.

What's the best way forward?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Product` class isn't `public`, which means it will be treated as `internal`. When you expose a property of type `Product` as `public` of a class that is itself `public` the property will be visible outside the current assembly. However, the `Product` class is `internal` and not visible. That's the inconsitency.

Either make your `Product` class `public` or your `Product` property `internal`.

As this is an MVC view model you probably want to use the `public` option to have the property visible to the view (the view is compiled in a separate assembly and cannot access `internal` properties of the view model).

Comment: Ahh, now that's what I thought. However, if I change the partial class to a public, I get (I am still learning which I am sure you have guessed)

Missing partial modifier on declaration of type Foo.Models.Product; another partial declaration of this type exists.

Comment: Ok, looks like I have sorted that, Might have been after I re inserted the table into the dbml table that another class was created.